# How does RCOUNT(1) works in OBIEE?

Tags: obiee

How does RCOUNT(1) works in OBIEE? I thought it was similar to ROWNUM of SQL. But in my report, more than one row, got the same serial number. This serial number got RCOUNT(1) in it's column formula. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you give up on this?

Answer (score 0):

You do an rcount on an expression just like the formula editor tells you.

- Geo     RCOUNT(Geo)
- North    1
- East    2
- South   3
- West    4

Comment: Could you please tell me how RCOUNT(1) works Chris? If it's the same as ROWNUM, it shouldn't repeat but that's not the case in my report

Comment: Default(Max) has been applied as an aggregation rule, for this row in column formula.

Comment: As written above: you "rcount" an expression like RCOUNT("Customer"."Customer Id") and not rcount(1)